# Clean way to access form options in event listener

Tags: forms, symfony

How can I access $options passed to buildForm() from an event listener in a clean way? Please see below code sample:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, [$this, 'preSetDataListener']);
    }

    public function preSetDataListener(FormEvent $event)
    {
        // how would I access $options from buildFrom here?
    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$event->getForm()->getConfig()->getOptions()
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't rely on `$event->getForm()->getConfig()->getOptions()`. It's not meant to be used by us. I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/12815) on the Symfony bug tracker with this problem and they told me to inherit variables into the anonymous function instead. [See this example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-167).

Pay attention to the `use` keyword.

```
->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
    // here you can use $options
}
```

That gets the `$options` array from the parent scope and injects it into the event listener function. It's a PHP feature.

Oh, and this means you'll have to either directly pass an anonymous function as an argument to `addEventListener()` (as in the example above) or define it inside `buildForm()` as a normal variable, like this:

```
$listener = function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
    // do something
}

$builder
    ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $listener);
```

Comment: Best solution for me.

Answer (score 4):

It's often handy to get them selected one instead of full array:

```
$event->getForm()->getConfig()->getOption('option_key')
```

If you need the full array however, go with Artur's suggestion:

```
$event->getForm()->getConfig()->getOptions()
```

Answer (score -2):

You can declare a class variable and copy options variables to that and access that class variable in your function.

Comment: This should be a comment